# Internationalization doesn't work or I don't know how to make it work

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

Settings.py constants

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Vilnius'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'lt'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

If I add `LocaleMiddleware` to the middleware classes and edit source code so that it would print my locale, it prints `lt` as expected.

Moreover:

`./manage.py makemessages -l lt` generated the file and I translated text occurences.

`./manage.py compilemessages` returns `processing file django.po in /Users/aemdy/PycharmProjects/rezervavau_v2/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES`

But sadly I still see english text in my pages.

I use django admin and the phrases included in the basic django admin are translated (Change password, password, edit and some others). Still, my own defined phrases are shown in english.

Comment: Are you getting some text translated or none?

Comment: Do you have any `fuzzy` tags in your .po file? Those lines need to be removed before compiling. Also, you need to restart your server for .mo file changes to take effect.

Comment: I know that, those lines are removed. I've edited my question, actually there are some translated phrases - django admin ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have found the answer myself.

I needed to add the following line in `settings.py`:

`LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../locale/'),)`

Comment: Also, you should change the order of your middleware classes. You should have SessionMiddleware before LocaleMiddleware (for this one uses that to discover user chosen language), and both should come before CommonMiddleware.