# Internationalization, some problems with switching languages

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I have a site in English and want to add Russian.
settings.py

> LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
>
> LANGUAGES = (
>       ('en', ('English')),
>       ('ru', ('Russian')), )
>
> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>       # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
>       # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', )

urls.py

> url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

Simple form grom django docs

```
> <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" id="language-select">
>        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
>             {% csrf_token %}
>             <select name="language">
>                 {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
>                     <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
>                 {% endfor %}
>             </select>
>        <input type="submit" value="Go" /> </form>
```

I install gettext, add 'locale' folder (in project folder, near manage.py). Create 'ru folder' with .po file and add some translations. But after language changing it returns [26/Jul/2013 13:43:32] "POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 and redirect to English page. What's wrong here?

Comment: You have in settings.py - USE_I18N=True  ?

Comment: Yes, USE_I18N = True, USE_L10N = True here

Comment: Do you have also the .mo file in locale/ru/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` **after** `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` and **before** `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`

Example:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help with main problem.

Comment: Сan you paste html-code that is generated by:

 {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
  <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
 {% endfor %}

And what values are in `LANGUAGES`?

Comment: In LANGUAGES  (('en', 'English'), ('ru', 'Russian')) . HTML code:<select name="language">
                
    <option value="en">English</option>
                
    <option value="ru">Russian</option>
                
             </select>

Comment: I find solution there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031753/internationalization-doesnt-work-or-i-dont-know-how-to-make-it-work?rq=1 . I have line LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'locale'),
) in settings, but it started work only when I change 'locale' to '../locale/'

Answer (score 0):

Did you use i18n_patterns in the urls.py for the URL that support both languages?

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^about/$', views.anything, name='about'),
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns